# 正規表現で、特定の単語が複数回出現する文字列を抽出することは可能でしょうか。

Tags: python, python3, 正規表現

正規表現で、特定の単語が複数回出現する文字列を抽出することは可能でしょうか。

例えば　犬というKWが　下記例の②のように2回以上出現している文字列を抽出したいです。

例
①犬はよく泣いています。
②その家の犬は良く吠える犬です。
③その犬はご飯を食べました。

※テキストエディタで対応できる方法を知りたいですが、もし可能であれば
正規表現でとありますが、(python勉強中のため)pythonを使って自動化する例も併せて知りたいです。

Comment: 量指定子(quantifier)を使って `(犬.*){2,}` としても良いかと思います。

Comment: ありがとうございました。このやり方でできました。
自分でも調べたとき(犬){2}かと推測しましたがこれだと"犬"が連続していないとうまくいかないようなのでだめでした。
(犬.*)とすることで、犬が含まれている文章を見つけ出し、{2,}とすることで、犬が２つ以上含まれていたら判定というやり方を知ったときは感動しました。ありがとうございました。

あと、含まれている特定文字列が含まれている、行ごと選択する場合はこちらを参考にした下記でできました。

Answer (score 6):

python による自動化になりますが、探す文字列が "犬" のように決まっており固定であるならば、
文字列の count メソッドを使用したフィルタリングが高速でよいと思います。
count メソッドを使うと、文字列に含まれる、特定の文字列の数を数えることができます。
(例えば `"abracadabra".count("abra")` は実行すると `2` となります。)
以下にコードを載せておきます。

```
def hantei(s, KW, th):
    return s.count(KW) >= th

strings = ["犬はよく泣いています。",
           "その家の犬は良く吠える犬です。",
           "その犬はご飯を食べました。"]

KW = "犬"
th = 2

filtered_strings = []
for s in strings:
    if hantei(s, KW, th):
        filtered_strings.append(s)

print(filtered_strings)
# Out: ['その家の犬は良く吠える犬です。']
```

参考までに、for 文のブロックを以下のように１行で書くこともできます。

```
filtered_strings = [s for s in strings if hantei(s, KW, th)]
```

Comment: このやり方で解決しました。
あと一つ恐縮ですが、外部のデータを読み込ませるためにはどのようにすればよいでしょうか。

犬についての文章が大量にあり、それらを別テキストファイルで管理している場合、テキストファイルの中身を読みに行き、プログラムで処理するというやり方です。

Comment: ディレクトリ構造、テキストの中身のフォーマットなどがわからないため、明確にお答えすることはできませんが、私の回答に記載の4-6行目の `strings = ["犬は...]` を `with open(filename) as f: strings = f.read().splitlines()` に置き換える (`filename` にはテキストファイルのパスの文字列をいれてください)と、`filename` のテキストファイルの１行１行が `strings` に格納されると思いますので、これで、ひとまずは一つのファイルのテキストに対してフィルタをかけることができると思います。

Answer (score 5):

「"犬" が 2 回以上出現している」というのは "犬" が少なくとも 2 回出現していれば良いので、`.*犬.*犬.*`  で検索できます。

Answer (score 2):

私初心者ですが、ちょうど今日Pythonの正規表現の勉強をしたところなので、やってみました。

```
slist = ['犬はよく泣いています。', 'その家の犬は良く吠える犬です。', 'その犬はご飯を食べました。']
for words in slist:
    found = re.findall(".*犬.*犬.*", words)
    for match in found:
        print(match)
```

インタプリタでやったのですが、以下のように真ん中の文だけ印字されました。

```
>>> その家の犬は良く吠える犬です。
```